# Newsletter emailing via mailchimp

Tags: email, html-email, mailchimp

I have a users database and I want to send them newsletters.
What is the easiest way to do that?

If I want to use, for example, mailchimp, how can I connect my user database to theirs email lists? Via the API?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can export you database as a .csv to import to mailchimp.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different choices. As you've mentioned Mailchimp, I'll assume that you're using that. Most ESPs offer similar functionality, so the same logic applies whether you're using Silverpop, CampaignMonitor, or any similar vendors.

1. Store your user database in MailChimp, and use their API to get information. There are quite a few downsides of this - performance will be slow and unreliable (your service will depend on Mailchimp's servers), and your schema will be bound to what MailChimp lets your do.
2. Store your user database on your side, and make an API that gets info from your database and pushes it into Mailchimp at runtime. This is complicated, and you won't get the full benefit of Mailchimp.
3. Synchronise your database on both servers, although only storing on Mailchimp the information you need to do your email marketing. You can synchronise manually - do a daily export from your database and import it into Mailchimp. Or you could write the data into Mailchimp either on a cronjob, or directly as the data is changed via an observer. Do regular data integrity checks to make sure that everything is working.
4. Don't use an ESP to hold your database. Use somebody like SendGrid as the SMTP server, and do everything else on your side. This is actually quite a neat option as it gives a lot of flexibility, but it requires the most technical skill.

The right option depends on a few things:

- How big is your list?
- How often do you send emails?
- What level of skill do you have (or have access to)?
- Legal issues, especially data protection